# How to print the output of ansible ad-hoc command from all the hosts in the inventory

Tags: ansible

When I execute an ansible ad-hoc command, output from each host is consolidated and not able to see all of them. I could not find any options to explicitly instruct ansible.

Currently this is what happens even with -f 1 option

```
$ ansible all -a hostname -i inventory.yaml -f 1
172.16.1.5 172.16.1.6 172.16.1.7 | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
node1
```

Instead I would like to see the output of `hostname` command from each hosts in the inventory on new lines.

Inventory file:

```
all:
 hosts:
    172.16.1.5 
    172.16.1.6 
    172.16.1.7
```

Comment: Are you quite sure that all three hosts don't have the name `node1`?

Comment: @MichaelHampton they all have different names (node1, node2, none3). The issue was with the missing : on the host entry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the inventory, I was missing the colon at the end of the host/IP and newer versions expects it.

```
all:
 hosts:
    172.16.1.5: 
    172.16.1.6: 
    172.16.1.7:
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put "-v" at the end

```
ansible all -a hostname -i inventory.yaml -f 1 -v
```